# How to achieve 'media does not exist' like whatsapp?

Tags: android, layout, android-imageview, whatsapp

What is the best way to achieve **"media does not exist"** with blur effect on original image which is already deleted (like WhatAapp),

And if WhatsApp store it in physical path (because you can also able to see it in offline mode), then where it exists?

[image]

Comment: may be Whatsapp database or memory of phone in folder android -> data-> `com.whatsapp`

Comment: @sushildlh i have checked in 'android -> data-> com.whatsapp', but not found

Comment: then may be they saved in caches or database

Answer (score 0):

You have to store image in database once delete should be blur effect on imageview